# Proper Way to open this URL in a C# app

Tags: c#, https

I have a URL that I want to open in my C# app. This URL is used to talk to a communications device, not an internet web site. I have gotten by (I think) all the cert stuff. But the text I get back in the program IS NOT the same thing that CORRECTLY displays when I use a web browser.

Here's the code.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Web;

namespace VMLConnStatus
    {
    class Program
        {
        static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new MyPolicy();

            // Create a request for the URL: https://192.168.30.15/cgi-bin/connstatus?202
            String url = "https://192.168.30.15/cgi-bin/";
            String data = "connstatus?202";

            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST";

            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = data;
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();

            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);

            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

    public class MyPolicy : ICertificatePolicy
        {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint srvPoint,
          X509Certificate certificate, WebRequest request,
          int certificateProblem)
            {
            //Return True to force the certificate to be accepted.
            return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

The result, though not perfectly displayed in Chrome, should be:

NA 
 NA 
 NA 
 NA 
 4c:cc:34:02:6d:26 
 00:23:A7:24:A3:B6

But the text I get in the console window is:

```
Ok
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Index of cgi-bin/</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#99cc99" TEXT="#000000" LINK="#2020ff" VLINK="#4040cc">
<H4>Index of cgi-bin/</H4>
<PRE>
<A HREF=".">.                               </A>    15Jun2014 09:48
 0
<A HREF="..">..                              </A>    15Jun2014 09:48
  0
<A HREF="connstatus">connstatus                      </A>    15Jun2014 09:48
      19580
<A HREF="firmwarecfg">firmwarecfg                     </A>    15Jun2014 09:48
       45736
<A HREF="webcm">webcm                           </A>    15Jun2014 09:48
 23836
</PRE>
<HR>
<ADDRESS><A HREF="http://www.acme.com/software/mini_httpd/">mini_httpd/1.19 19de
c2003</A></ADDRESS>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Not EVEN close to the same thing.

What am I doing wrong?

Chuck

UPDATE: Code changed. URL, GET, and request writing (presuming I understood the directions). New code is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new MyPolicy();

    // Create a request for the URL: https://192.168.30.15/cgi-bin/connstatus?202
    String url = "https://192.168.30.15/cgi-bin/connstatus?202";

    // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

    // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
    request.Method = "GET";

    // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    // Get the request stream.
    //Now it throws an exception here--------------------------------
    //"Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type."
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

    // Close the Stream object.
    dataStream.Close();

    // Get the response.
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    // Display the status.
    Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

    // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

    // Read the content.
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

    // Display the content.
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);

    // Clean up the streams.
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();
    Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: You are receiving back the directory structure of your IIS shouldn't you be doing a get with the following URL https://192.168.30.15/cgi-bin/connstatus?202

Comment: You're making a POST request to a URL that is clearly a GET request. Just change the URL to `https://192.168.30.15/cgi-bin/connstatus?202`, don't write anything to the request stream, and set the method to `GET`. Done.

Comment: Rob, I made your suggested changes and I'm getting a new exception, as noted in the updated code at the bottom of my original posting: "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type."

Answer (score 2):

You are using http method POST but the url you have in the comment looks more like GET so then you probably need `WebRequest.Create(url + data)`.

The incorrect response is the index page for `https://192.168.30.15/cgi-bin/` which if you put into Chrome will give you the same "wrong" response.

You might not need to write any data to the request stream and can change the `Method` and `ContentType` for the request.

Answer (score 0):

The solution required two parts.

First, doing the proper things, thus a total code rework.

I had the dreaded "The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=Header name is invalid". I tried to make the programatic solution for this work, but it is a .NET 2.0 solution and I was not able to figure it out in .NET4+. So, I edited the .config file and went on.

Here's the final code:

```
        //Initialization
        HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://192.168.30.15/cgi-bin/connstatus?202");

        //method is GET.
        WebReq.Method = "GET";

        //Get the response handle
        HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();

        //read the response
        Stream Answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader _Answer = new StreamReader(Answer);

        //display it
        Console.WriteLine(_Answer.ReadToEnd());

        //pause for the ENTER key
        Console.ReadLine();
```

This was added to the .config file in the debug folder (and would be added in the Release folder also..... using VS2013)

```
<system.net>
<settings>
<httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing = "true"/>
</settings>
</system.net>
```

Thank-you to everyone that replied. The inspiration helped me get to the solution.